# How to pass a string?

Tags: java, json, retrofit, retrofit2

When I pass the string, the % is converted to %25 in the entire line. How can I avoid this?

**String:** %7B%22phone%22%3A%20%2289261234567

**Request:**

```
    @Headers({"Accept:application/json", "Content-Type:application/json;"})
    @POST("RemoteCall?method=Taxi.WebAPI.NewOrder")
    Call<RegResponse>newOrder(@Header("Cookie") String setCookie,@Query("params") String params);
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried sending the string without having encoded it yourself?  `"{\"phone\": \"89261234567"`?  (Although it feels like there's some things missing there...)

Comment: What you offer will certainly work. But I would like a hard code

Comment: Pass `java.io.URLDecoder.decode(yourString);` in the method call?